# How to make a BitCoin API call using PHP?

Tags: php

I am making a website that gets information about a bitcoin wallet balance. What I am trying to achieve is for whatever the persons text input is to be sent to the link but sent like "http://link.com/ + input"

I am new to PHP so I am not sure what to do next or what I have done wrong so far.

```
<?php
        echo ' <form action="https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/" method="post">
  BTC Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>'
$input = $_POST['post'];

echo $input
        ?>
```

Comment: Post your code on your question not pastebin.

Comment: Do I now have to guess, that you want the value from the form which you are printing?

Comment: Where does `$_POST['post']` come from? What do you expect `$input` to be? What is `http://link.com`?  -- you see, we can't answer your question when you leave us with more of our own.

Comment: I mean't $_POST['address']
and link.com is https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/ + the users input

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes that is what I want. I wrote it wrong. and the link is https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/ and then I want it to return the data from blockchain.info on my webpage so it shows the balance of a users bitcoin address.

Comment: Please always use specific and meaningful titles, both here and in any programming forum on the web; consider how useful the front page would be if all posts were called "I am not sure where to go next with this".

Answer (score 0):

Old Answer:

> [Use string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $link = "http://link.com" . $input;
> ```

**Update**:

It seems like what you actually want to do is to redirect the user based on their input. For this, you should use the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Here is an example as to how you can use the function for redirection purposes.

```
header('Location: ' . $link);
die();
```

Note that this must go at the very top of the page, before any HTML is outputted. (So of course, your code for `$link` should go before it as well)

As for your `<form action="https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/" method="post">`, you will want to change the action to *the current document*. This is because `$_POST['post']` only receives data *after* you pressed submit. Changing it to `action=""` generally defaults to this behavior.

Comment: how about fixing the rest of the code to ?

Comment: I have done that, I am still getting a internal 500 error. Did I do something wrong with getting the user input?

Comment: @Neal Well, according to the code you posted, it seems like you are lacking semi-colons as far as I can tell.

Comment: I added semi-colins, it has displayed the page now, but when I input the bitcoin address, it just takes me to the page that I have set.

Comment: @Neal This is because your form has `action="https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/"`. This means that you are sending your POST data to https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/. Your script will never get the `$_POST`. Take a look at my updated answer.